# ModelState.IsValid Returning Incorrect Type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, modelstate

I have an ASP.NET application and I'm trying to use `ModelState.IsValid` to return error messages if the query is flawed. I tried something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
[Route("{id:int}")]
public IQueryable<ToDoTable> Get(int id = -1)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var errorList = (from item in ModelState
                         where item.Value.Errors.Any()
                         select item.Value.Errors[0].ErrorMessage).ToList();
        return errorList.AsQueryable();
    }
    else
    {
        if (id == -1)
            return db.ToDoTables;
        else
            return db.ToDoTables.Where(lt => lt.ID == id);
    }
}
```

However, the problem is that `errorList` is of type `string` and the function is expecting a return type of `ToDoTable`, a class that I made. How do I get the correct return type? Or do I need to change the function's expectations? Do I have to add the method into the class instead (not even sure that would work)?

When `ModelState.IsValid` is true, the function is returning class objects with information gathered from the database I'm querying and outputs it as JSON. Example:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 11,
    "Title": "this is a test",
    "Description": "this is specifically to test the put method",
    "Due": null,
    "Completed": true
  },
  {
    "ID": 15,
    "Title": "date test",
    "Description": "datetime format",
    "Due": "2015-08-10T02:41:29",
    "Completed": true
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach that I have used in the past is to return an [HttpResponseMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage%28v=vs.118%29.aspx!) from the method.

This will allow you to return an 'error' type (for example https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-http-problem) and appropriate response code (e.g. 400).

Your function then becomes:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
[Route("{id:int}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id = -1)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var errorList = (from item in ModelState
                         where item.Value.Errors.Any()
                         select item.Value.Errors[0].ErrorMessage).ToList();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errorList);
    }
    else
    {

        var tables = (id == -1) ? db.ToDoTables : db.ToDoTables.Where(lt => lt.ID == id);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, tables);
    }
}
```

This means that you can cope with differing response types and statuses without throwing HttpResponseExceptions.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you. This makes a lot more sense than the `IQueryable` I had before.

Comment: I have a quick question on that if statement syntax. What if I was doing an if statement very similar to my question but I wanted to delete an item in the database rather than return a value? How would I modify it to call delete methods that don't return any values?

Comment: If you have deleted something you can split up the If statement rather than use ternary operator (?:) and after deleting you could return a 204 "No Content" response: return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);

Answer (score 0):

Think from your consumers. How are you going to communicate and document this? "This API call returns a Foo, except for in cases where it returns Bar".

That *is* possible, but then you need to either change the return type to an `IHttpActionResult` or [`throw new HttpResponseException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732644/best-practice-to-return-errors-in-asp-net-web-api).

(Arguably) better would be to introduce a response container with nullable properties, something like this:

```
public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    public int? RecordCount { get; set; }

    public T Content { get; set; }

    public ErrorDetail Error { get; set; }
}
```

This way all your operations can benefit from being statically-typed (think unit tests) and return success and failure in the same way.

Related: [Handle ModelState Validation in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686690/handle-modelstate-validation-in-asp-net-web-api), [Best practice to return errors in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732644/best-practice-to-return-errors-in-asp-net-web-api), [Storing result of Web API call into Generic type class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885411/storing-result-of-web-api-call-into-generic-type-class),